# Really, why does XCode always report every compile error twice?

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors

So, get this:  Ever since I've started using XCode to handle my software development (Objective C), I've tolerated the fact that every compile error (every) is being reported twice.  I've never had an error count that was an odd number!

So, if I have one syntax error, Xcode reports it twice.  This is the same for even the static analyzer errors.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456361/why-is-xcode-3-displaying-multiple-compiler-errors-or-warnings-for-each-that-actu).  Basically, you are probably compiling for more than one architecture (PPC & Intel or iPhone & iPad), which means everything gets counted once per architecture.

Annoys the heck out of me!

Comment: Arsenius, thanks!  This hasn't slowed me down, but it continues to be drag.